# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' mysql

Tags: mysql

First of all I know that there is a lot similar/the same issues descibed on stackOverflow, however, I spend last two days to find resolution of the issue for me, and it still doesn't work.

My database structure looks like:
- Table structure
[image]

- table indexes
  [image]

[image]

- table foreign key
  [image]
- data in the table 
  [image]

And now I try do SQL INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO `DBNAME`.`USERS` (`USER_TYPE`, `USER_ID`, `CREATION_DATE`, `EMAIL`, `ENABLED`, `FIRST_NAME`,`LAST_NAME`, `LAST_ACCESS`, `LAST_MODIFIED`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`,`MAX_SUB_ACCOUNTS`, `PARENT_USER_ID`) 
VALUES 
('SUB_ACCOUNT', '149', '2018-06-14 20:17:51', 'mail@host.com', '1', 'John','Porter', '2018-07-05 18:31:31', '2018-07-05 18:31:31', 'DS','1234','', '147');
```

or without user_Id, because it should be auto incremented:

```
INSERT INTO `DBNAME`.`USERS` (`USER_TYPE`, `CREATION_DATE`, `EMAIL`, `ENABLED`, `FIRST_NAME`,`LAST_NAME`, `LAST_ACCESS`, `LAST_MODIFIED`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`,`MAX_SUB_ACCOUNTS`, `PARENT_USER_ID`) 
VALUES 
('SUB_ACCOUNT', '2018-06-14 20:17:51', 'mail@host.com', '1', 'John','Porter', '2018-07-05 18:31:31', '2018-07-05 18:31:31', 'DS','1234','', '147');
```

I don't know but I always getting:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Have you checked the table itself to make sure that there is only one row with the USER_ID=0?

Comment: Yes, I checked. I have not USER_ID=0 in my table. Actually, I have only 14 records there.